# Installing SteamOS on chromebook

Tags: gui, steam, chromebook

I have Ubuntu 12.04 with Unity installed on my Chromebook using Crouton.

To install SteamOS in Unity normally, all you need to do is install SteamOS Compositor and SteamOS Modeswitch Inhibitor and you can then choose the SteamOS GUI from the login screen. I don't have access to the login screen. Logging out just closes Ubuntu and takes me back to ChromeOS.

Running:

`ls -l /usr/share/xsessions/`

Gives me:

> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 134 oct 23 2013 steamos.desktop

Along with the similar GUI info, so I know it's there, I just don't know how to switch to it.

Comment: Why don't you just use the normal Steam with Big Picture?

Comment: I have done this and aside from a bit of flicking, it works well.
There's not really any point in using the SteamOS GUI, it was more just wondering if it were possible.

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally speaking the desktop manager (LightDM in Ubuntu's case) would offer you some sort of choice at login.

Crouton seems to be [hacked together](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/blob/master/chroot-bin/gnome-session-wrapper) in such a way that there is no login or choice of desktop. It's just manually passing session files to `xinit`. You could probably expand on that ([here's how](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/search?q=startgnome) the [`startgnome` script](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/blob/master/chroot-bin/startgnome) is called), but we're getting an extremely long way away from how Ubuntu works.

As a comment above suggests, just using Steam in Big Picture mode might make more sense, even if you have to script something to fall back to another compositor.